# Why there is a Whitespace in my HTML textarea, when I have placeholder in it?

Tags: html, wordpress, css

In the WordPress, I have custom Form and below is the `textarea`:

```
<textarea type="text" name="text" rows="4" placeholder="message here"><?php echo esc_textarea($_POST['text']); ?></textarea>
```

However, the `textarea` shows whitespace in the browser.
Upon clearing the `textarea` by selecting inside it and deleting the whitespaces, it shows the `placeholder` text.

Image attached: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZyFJ.jpg

Comment: Interesting its happening only in FireFox. Tried Opera & IE, this issue is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<textarea type="text" name="text" rows="4" placeholder="message here"><?php echo trim(esc_textarea($_POST['text'])); ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you have in `$_POST['text']`? You should be sure, that is really empty.

Maybe is better to use:

```
<textarea type="text" name="text" rows="4" placeholder="message here">
  <?php if (isset($_POST['text']) && !empty($_POST['text'])) {
    echo $_POST['text'];
  }; ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Tried that, still got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Why there is a Whitespace in my HTML textarea, when I have placeholder in it?

Because the return value of `esc_textarea($_POST['text'])` is not an empty string.

> Upon clearing the textarea by selecting inside it and deleting the whitespaces, it shows the placeholder text.

Spaces, new lines and other whitespace are data. They count as a value.

If you have a value, the value is shown. The placeholder is only shown if there is no value.

As you have discovered, deleting the value will cause the placeholder to be shown.

Comment: I have tested removing the `<?php echo esc_textarea($_POST['text']); ?>` and still this issue is there.

Comment: This is only in FF. Opera, Edge & IE are fine.

Comment: @theKing — I can't reproduce the problem you describe: http://jsbin.com/yiwegoy/2/edit?html,output

Comment: I agree; but it was strange.